# How to convert Calendar with timezone offset of 2 digits?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm converting a `Calendar` to String with format hh:mm+-UTCoffset, like `13:37-0500`.
How can I just format the calendar with timezone limited to 2 digits? (and moreover: what are 4 digits for? Aren't timezone differences always 2 digits?)

To truncate the last two digits, this is my method at the moment:

```
DateFormatUtils.format(date, "HH:mmZ").substring(0, 8);
```

But couldn't this be done more elegant? I fell substringing is not the right thing to do here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is only for your second question:

> what are 4 digits for? Aren't timezone differences always 2 digits?

There is at least one timezone, the Middle East Time used in Iran which is defined as GMT +3.5, so just two digits wouldn't fit for this timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Use `X` insted of `Z`. Look at sample code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mmX");
    Date date=new Date();
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

**Output**: 18:44+06

Comment: yes, IF you havea `Date`. But I have a `Calendar` object, and parsing this is not possible with `SimpleDateFormat`. ``Calendar.getTime()` provides the reference `Date` using timeinmillis, but then it does not show the proper offset anmyore...